# Where are the logs for commands executed as root in AWS Linux 2 AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux-2

Can't find them, there's no .bash_history. Also checked at /var/log/audit and /var/log/secure* Maybe they don't even exist or are disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just running `history`?

Comment: Yes, only have the ones for the session. That's why I mentioned audit/secure logs, where you can, usually, check old bash history.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the history file for root isn't being set. You can confirm this by running:

```
echo $HISTFILE
```

from your root shell. You can set this in the .bashrc in the /root (the home dir for the root user) by placing the line:

```
HISTFILE="/root/.bash_history"
```

at the end of your .bashrc file.

Note - The reason your history for the current session is viewable using

```
history
```

is because the bash history isn't actually written to the history file that is configured for that user until the user exits their session or it's terminated.

Comment: It's there, but only has the history for the session. Would look for a quick workaround to get a persisten file and post it in here, for me, it's super useful, like when I create kubernetes cluster with options, re using commands saves me lots of time.